# bitcoin-core: error getting block (pruned data)

Tags: bifrost

Does somebody knows when this occurs?

```
time="2018-03-27T14:24:48Z" level=error msg="Error getting block from bitcoin-core: -1: Block not available (pruned data)" blockHash=00000000e09a54870a260a7e80b1acdf3b29a545d07b745a3ef3c36d4c8641ba pid=27 service=BitcoinListener 
time="2018-03-27T14:24:48Z" level=error msg="Error getting block" blockNumber=630241 err="Error getting block from bitcoin-core: -1: Block not available (pruned data)" pid=27 service=BitcoinListener
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You likely have [prune mode](https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/5ywru2/what_is_the_prune_mode_exactly/) turned on in bitcoin-core. Turn it off.

Comment: yes, I do to save disk space